# When two-weapon fighting, can a Battle Master fighter use a maneuver on the Attack action and another on the bonus-action attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, combat-maneuver, two-weapon-fighting, battle-master

The Battle Master fighter's Combat Superiority feature states that *“you can use only one maneuver per attack” (PHB 73)*, but I’m unsure how that applies in the case of two-weapon fighting.

Is striking an opponent with your bonus action considered a separate attack, or part of the original attack?

Comment: Related: [What counts as an attack?](/questions/71245), [What does upper-case-A-Attack action vs. lower-case-a-attack mean?](/questions/105781)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

PHB says, regarding Maneuvers that:

> You can use only one maneuver per attack.

In regards of two-weapong fighting, PBH says:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon
>   that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack
>   with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other
>   hand.

So RAW, you could use a maneuver with each attack, as it says you can one per attack, not per Attack action.
Of course, you're limited by your amount of superiority dice:

> A superiority die is expended when you use it.

Comment: Note that even if it did say once per Attack action you could still do it twice with Two-Weapon Fighting

Comment: Are you sure? The bonus action is not an Attack action.

Comment: @sevenbrokenbricks Actually... My comment above seems unlikely, I'll search around the rulebooks to see if I can find an example of similar text to ask about

Comment: by this logic you can also use maneuvers during attacks of opportunity and any kind of reaction "Attack" you may have acquired, im not saying that is wrong, im just pointing this out

Comment: @Nullman Indeed, some can be quite fun (one of my players like to use his Trip Attack when he has an AoO, he doesn't have Sentinel *yet*), but the limited amount of Superiority Dice balance it quite nicely IMHO.

Comment: @NahynOklauq very reminiscent of the factotum of 3.5e, you supernova all your special moves very quickly

Comment: Note that you can also use a maneuver on each attack *within the attack action* once you get Extra Attack. Makes for some fun turns at level 5+, in combination with Action Surge.